# debugging aspx page that gives a little stack trace?

Tags: asp.net

My aspx page gives randomly this small stack trace:

Error Message:

> Input string was not in a correct
>   format. Stack Trace: at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String
>   Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat)
>   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Comp

why page is not displaying the full details in which function the error occurs?

Now i cannot locate the bug.. usually it gives lines numbers etc.

Comment: error msg is sent to me by email by application error handler in global.asax

Answer (score 0):

Check your web.config has debug="true"
(Which it probably has, otherwise you wouldn't see that message even),
and
Check your pdb file is in your bin folder.

It's also possible that you're using a custom component which is trapping an error, and only displaying that portion of it, via a label.

Comment: yes, I believe its components causing it, any ideas how to debug it further, should I disable exception handlers from it ? (  I have sourcecode for it )

Comment: Possibly modify the code to return the method the error is occuring in, as well as the values of any input parameters to the method. (or page.). That should give you a clue, allowing you to debug it with the same inputs as what's causing the issue.